# Выровнять ul li по высоте родительского блока div

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер всем, подскажите пожалуйста, как выровнять `ul li` внутри блока `div` по всей высоте и ширине, то есть если `div` становится меньше или больше то `li` желательно чтоб заполняли всё пространство? Делаю выпадающий список, элементы должны располагаться вертикально.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>11111111111111</li>
        <li>2222222222</li>
        <li>3333333333333</li>
        <li>4444444444</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  height: 25%;
  outline: 1px dottes blue;
}

li:hover {
  background: silver;
}

li:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div { 
  animation: h 3s linear infinite;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@keyframes h {
  0% { height: 6em; }
  50% { height: 18em; }
  100% { height: 6em; }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>11111111111111</li>
    <li>2222222222</li>
    <li>3333333333333</li>
    <li>4444444444</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
div{
  padding:20px 4px;
  background:#ccc;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px;
}
div h3{
  text-align:center;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
div ul{
  background:#f3f5f6;
  border-right:3px solid #f3f5f6;
}
ul li{
  list-style:none;
  display:block;
  background:#ccc;
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #f3f5f6;
  position:relative;
}
ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#f3f5f6;
}
ul>li:nth-child(3)>ul{
  position:absolute;
  left:-210px; top:-1000px;
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  border-left:3px solid #f3f5f6;
  display:non;
  z-index:-3;
  transition:.5s;-webkit-transition:.5s;-moz-transition:;.5s
  }
ul>li>ul:after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:-20px;
  z-index:10;
}
ul>li:nth-child(3):hover ul{
  display:block;
  left:210px; top:0;
  z-index:9;
}
div>ul>li:nth-child(3):after{
  content:'';
  border:10px solid transparent;
  border-left:10px solid #fefefe;
  position:absolute;
  right:-3px; top:5px;
}
```

```html
<div> 
<h3>Меню проэкта</h3>
   <ul> 
       <li><a href="#">первая ссылка меню</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">вторая ссылка меню</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">третья ссылка меню</a> 
           <ul> 
              <li><a href="#">первая из третьего</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">вторая ссылка из 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">третья ссылка из 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">это ссылка 4 из 3</a></li>
           </ul>       
       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">это ссылка о авторе</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

вот так наверно ??

Comment: Классно сделано, спасибо, а можно что б при нажатии на "третья ссылка меню" новое подменю открывалось не рядом а выпадало в низ, тем самым отодвигаю блок "эта ссылка о авторе" в низ. Что б меню и подменю выпадало в низ.

Comment: а - ну типа - http://jqueryui.com/accordion/  что ли ??

Comment: вот мазёвый => http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_animate

Comment: оо точно, аккордеон в самый раз будет, пасибо огромное , щас зарегаюсь  и всем плюсиков натыкаю)

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LTxj/Pmy1PPr23  вот ещё один на чистом css3

Answer (score 0):

Проблема следующего кода в том, что бы выровнять вертикально содержимое `li`. Что бы обойти проблему, внутри `li` используем `div` и для него делаем в-центрирование, хотя маркеры `li` элементов так и остаются не в-центрированными.

```css
.div0 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: orchid;
}
.ul0 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: violet;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.ul0 li {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: pink;
}
li div{
  padding: auto 0;
   margin: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   transform: translate(0, 50%) } 
}
li:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="div0">
  <ul class="ul0">
    <li>
      <div>11111111111111</div>
    </li>
    <li>2222222222</li>
    <li>3333333333333</li>
    <li>4444444444</li>
    <ul>
</nav>
```